# FFT differential equations

Tags: fourier-analysis, computer-science, fourier-series, matlab, computational-mathematics

Given a generical differential equation what is the procedure to solve it using fft command. Can anyone explain me how to do it?

For example:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+10\cdot \frac{d\:y}{dt}=-5\cdot t^2+t^4\cdot \cosh \left(t\right)$$

Should we use it as a discrete or as a continuous time transformation?
I think fft is for discrete time but that way we have not got the rule of differentiation.

Thanks

Comment: I'm only seeing an ode?

Comment: @Chinny84 It is true but how does it is solved???

Comment: I do not know off the top of my head but math works does have plenty of material for all the toolboxes (except when trying to do something hairy with ne builder) so I would consult there in the meantime .. This is assuming you are using Matlab (from the tags).